# Using the SonarQube tasks for Azure DevOps Server 2020 how can I suppress all the static code analysis, but upload the coverage report?

Tags: c#, azure-devops, msbuild, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I have a build which:

- Runs dotCover to produce coverage report
- Includes SQ Prepare and Analyze tasks to upload the coverage reports to SQ.

The code is old and has gazillion static code analysis issues. I decided to suppress the SQ static code analysis globally by setting `SonarQubeExclude = true` build variable at queue time.

The problem is that SQ Analyze task fails:

```
##[section]Starting: Run SQ Analysis
==============================================================================
Task         : Run Code Analysis
Description  : Run scanner and upload the results to the SonarQube server.
Version      : 4.18.0
Author       : sonarsource
Help         : Version: 4.18.0. This task is not needed for Maven and Gradle projects since the scanner should be run as part of the build.

[More Information](http://redirect.sonarsource.com/doc/install-configure-scanner-tfs-ts.html)
==============================================================================
[command]...
SonarScanner for MSBuild 5.1
Using the .NET Framework version of the Scanner for MSBuild
Post-processing started.
23:11:35.03  The exclude flag has been set so the project will not be analyzed. Project file: SomeProject.csproj
...
23:11:35.03  The exclude flag has been set so the project will not be analyzed. Project file: SomeProject2.csproj
##[error]23:11:35.046  No analysable projects were found. SonarQube analysis will not be performed. Check the build summary report for details.
23:11:35.046  No analysable projects were found. SonarQube analysis will not be performed. Check the build summary report for details.
23:11:35.03  The exclude flag has been set so the project will not be analyzed. Project file: SomeProject3.csproj
...
23:11:35.046  The exclude flag has been set so the project will not be analyzed. Project file: SomeProject4.csproj
23:11:35.046  Generation of the sonar-properties file failed. Unable to complete the analysis.
##[error]23:11:35.046  Post-processing failed. Exit code: 1
23:11:35.046  Post-processing failed. Exit code: 1
##[error]The process '...
##[section]Finishing: Run SQ Analysis
```

This aborts the SQ Analysis task and no coverage reports are uploaded.

I understand that one way to fix it is create a Quality Gate with no static code analysis rules and configure the respective SQ project to use it.

Can I make it work without touching the SQ server side configuration? I do not understand why `SonarQubeExclude` at the end failed the SQ Analysis task.

More or less the same YAML template is reused by many builds some turn off SQ tasks, some turn them on (conditional YAML), but what I cannot do is stick the SQ Prepare task in the middle - so either it is turned off or turned on and runs before all the builds.

The SQ Prepare task:

```
  - task: SonarQubePrepare@4
    displayName: Prepare CI SQ Analysis
    inputs:
      SonarQube: SonarQube
      scannerMode: MSBuild
      projectKey: $(SonarQubeProjectKey)
      projectName: $(SonarQubeProjectName)
      projectVersion: $(SonarQubeProjectVersion)
      extraProperties: |
        sonar.cs.vscoveragexml.reportsPaths=$(Common.TestResultsDirectory)\vstest-coverage\*.xml
        sonar.cs.dotcover.reportsPaths=$(Common.TestResultsDirectory)\coverage\*.CoverageResult.html
        sonar.cs.opencover.reportsPaths=$(Common.TestResultsDirectory)\coverage\*.CoverageResult.xml
        sonar.cs.nunit.reportsPaths=$(Common.TestResultsDirectory)\tests\*.TestResult.xml
        sonar.inclusions=**/*.cs
        sonar.branch.name=$(SonarQubeSourceBranch)
        sonar.scm.disabled=true
```

The SQ Analysis Task:

```
      - task: SonarQubeAnalyze@4
        displayName: "Run SQ Analysis"
```

I omitted the conditions for clarity.

All the builds occur between these two tasks.

Is it possible to suppress static code analysis at all and just upload the coverage reports without changing the server side settings?

Answer (score 0):

> I do not understand why SonarQubeExclude at the end failed the SQ Analysis task.

Setting that property effectively tells the scanner to act as if that MSBuild project doesn't exist, so no issues or coverage will be reported.
If you've excluded all of the MSBuild projects then the scanner will complain there is nothing to upload.

> Can I make it work without touching the SQ server side configuration?

There isn't a supported way of doing this, no. The supported options are to upload the issues and coverage but just not ignore the issues, or to create a Quality Profile with no active rules as you described.

On argument in favour of running an analysis on old code is to detect security vulnerabilities so at least you are aware of them. It might be worth creating a limited Quality Profile that just contains the security rules, and use that.

Comment: There is also rationale not to run static code analysis at all on old code. This should be left to the discretion of the user.

Comment: Why don't you want to do that using a custom Quality Profile?

Comment: Because it makes it more difficult to control per solution. Several solutions are built. Some are old and some are new. For the old ones I want to disable the static code analysis, but for the new ones I want it to be enabled. How do you suggest to do it?